# python multithreading join causes hang

Tags: python, multithreading, join

I'm using the threading module in python to do some tests on I/O bound processing.

Basically, I am simply reading a file, line by line and writing it out concurrently.

I put the reading and writing loops in separate threads and use a Queue to pass data between:

```
q = Queue()
rt = ReadThread(ds)
wt = WriteThread(outBand)

rt.start()
wt.start()
```

If I run it as above, it works fine, but the interpreter crashes at the end of execution. (Any ideas why?)

If I add:

```
rt.join()
wt.join()
```

at the end, the interpreter simply hangs. Any ideas why?

The code for the ReadThread and WriteThread classes is as follows:

```
class ReadThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ds):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ds = ds #The raster datasource to read from

    def run(self):
        reader(self.ds)

class WriteThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ds):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ds = ds #The raster datasource to write to

    def run(self):
        writer(self.ds)        


def reader(ds):
    """Reads data from raster, starting with a chunk for three lines then removing/adding a row for the remainder"""

    data = read_lines(ds)
    q.put(data[1, :]) #add to the queue
    for i in np.arange(3, ds.RasterYSize):        
        data = np.delete(data, 0, 0)
        data = np.vstack([data, read_lines(ds, int(i), 1)])            
        q.put(data[1,:]) # put the relevant data on the queue


def writer(ds):
    """ Writes data from the queue to a raster file """
    i = 0
    while True:
        arr = q.get()
        ds.WriteArray(np.atleast_2d(arr), xoff = 0, yoff = i)
        i +=1
```

Comment: what is `outBand` and `ds`? If it's an endless loop of writing/reading then `.join()` will hang forever because it expects the thread to return some sort of value. From the Python docs on `.join()` - *Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.*

Comment: How does the interpreter crashes?

Answer (score 0):

Call `q.get()` will block infinitely in case your `Queue` is empty.

You can try to use `get_nowait()`, but you have to make sure that by the time you get to the `writer` function, there is something in the `Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

`wt.join()` waits for the thread to finish, which it never does because of the infinite loop around `q.get()` in `writer`. To make it finish, add

```
q.put(None)
```

as the last line of `reader`, and change `writer` to

```
def writer(ds):
    """ Writes data from the queue to a raster file """
    for i, arr in enumerate(iter(q.get, None)):
        ds.WriteArray(np.atleast_2d(arr), xoff = 0, yoff = i)
```

`iter(q.get, None)` yields values from `q` until `q.get` returns `None`. I added `enumerate` just for the sake of simplifying the code further.